# Python Detect Alert

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to make my python script detect an alert box on a page

```
import urllib2
url = raw_input("Please enter your url: ")
if urllib2.urlopen(url).read().find("<script>alert('alert');</script>") == 0:
    print "Alert Detected!"
```

How can I make it detect the alert?

Comment: Can you please provide more information? Does your sample code work at all? Have you confirmed that `<script>alert('alert');</script>` is the HTML code for the alert you are trying to find?

Comment: I coded the page, it's in there.

Answer (score 1):

`urllib2.urlopen(url).read().find("<script>alert('alert');</script>") == 0` to
`urllib2.urlopen(url).read().find("<script>alert('alert');</script>") >= 0`

Comment: Right, it would only be `== 0` if it matches the first character in the file.